# I can't click on my navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am struggling to get the Navigation drawer items to register and start and intent for a new activity. The drawer opens fine and is displayed correctly but nothing happens when I click on the items in the list. Here is my code

```
package radiofm.arabel;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import static android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ImageButton id_play,id_pause;

    private Button btn;
    private boolean playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean initialStage = true;


    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;






    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Log.d("myTag", "This is my toolbar");


        id_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.id_play);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        id_play.setEnabled(true);
        id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        id_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                    if (initialStage) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my excute");
                        new Player().execute("http://arabelfm.ice.infomaniak.ch/arabelprodcastfm.mp3");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my beforestart");

                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            Log.d("myTag", "This is my afterstart");

                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }

                    playPause = true;

                } else {
                    id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    Log.d("myTag", "This is my beforestop");

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is afterstop");

                        mediaPlayer.reset();

                    }

                    playPause = false;
                }
            }
        });




        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }



    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Boolean prepared = false;

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        Log.d("myTag", "This is my listnner");
                        initialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        id_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
//                Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            initialStage = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            //progressDialog.show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void displaySelectedScreen(int id)
    {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        Log.d("myTag", "This is my displ");

        switch (id){
            case R.id.nav_alarm:
                fragment = new Add_Alarm();
                break;

        }

        if (fragment !=null)
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_main,fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;




        if (id == R.id.nav_alarm) {

            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main,fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not doing anything with your menu item click in your `onOptionsItemSelected()` method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change your code inside **onNavigationItemSelected** to this:

```
    switch (item.getItemId()){
                      case R.id.nav_alarm:
                            //do stuff
                            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                       break;
            }
            FragmentTransaction ft =getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_main,fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your **onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)** method because while replacing the fragment you initailized you fragment null like    **Fragment fragment = null;**  .So, for replace the fragment you need to take actual fragment instead of null fragmnet.
You may go through about the [fragments here.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/149112/android-fragments-tutorial-introduction)

`

Answer (score 0):

```
Change the flow of the code as below:

  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        item.setCheckable(false);
        Fragment fragment=null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                 break
        }
        loadHomeFragment(fragment);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

       private void loadHomeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```